# How does this piece of code function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I was looking over some code a few minutes ago and this confuses me.

```
$("nav a").mouseenter(function() {
  audio.play();
});
```

I know '$' is jQuery for document.getElementById(""); and mouseEnter is an event handler for 'nav a' but how is the function assigned to the event? It doesn't have any assignment operator '='?

I don't know to much about jQuery right now as I'm trying to completely get JavaScript down. So when I went to modify the code to be pure JavaScript it doesn't seem to work...

```
document.getElementById("playAudio").onclick(function () {
   audio.play();
});
```

I don't understand why? I figured it was the same code?...

Answer (score 1):

mouseenter is a function. Similar to:

```
var element = {elm: document.getElementById('test')};
element.mouseenter = function(func) {
    element['elm'].addEventListener('mouseenter', func);
};
element.mouseenter(function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a function object (created with a function expression) to `jQuery.mouseenter`, and jQuery takes it from there.

FYI, part of what you're trying to get down here is the Document Object Model (DOM).  You're trying to make the code pure JavaScript + DOM API.  It's good to learn the fundamentals of both JS and the DOM, but be aware that jQuery smoothes out many inconsistencies in browsers' implementations of the DOM, such as registering event listeners.

Comment: I definitely want to learn jQuery after I get down the fundamentals of JS and the DOM. It's difficult to learn the fundamentals in this day and age because so many people are moving over to jQuery. I can't blame them though, its an amazing tool.

Answer (score 0):

The function is passed, and the function is anonymous (doesn't have a name).

You could also do:

```
function foo() { audio.play(); }

$('nav a').mouseenter(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

The dollar symbol is not just limited to `getElementById()`, it the the jQuery object and in your case, is calling the `nav` element then grabbing the `a` tags within the `nav`. After grabbing the element(s), it then attaches the event anonymously, allowing the function to run whenever the event is fired.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know alot about jQuery. I'm just trying to work with JavaScript until I learn most of the language then I'll be happy to mess around with jQuery. When I modify the code to be pure JavaScript it does not seem to work... document.getElementById("playAudio").onclick(function () {
            audio.play();
        });

Comment: The onclick() and mouseenter() events are jQuery functions that are attached via the selector. In regular JavaScript, you need to assign the event a little different; something like: `document.getElementById("playAudio").onclick=function(){audio.play();};`. Check out the [jQuery website](http://www.jquery.com) for more information on their syntax.

Comment: I looked on there but I don't know where to read about it at. So much documentation! Before I delve into jQuery I want to have a full understanding of JavaScript. Unfortunately alot of people have moved over to jQuery and that make it difficult for me to learn regular JavaScript. So with regular JS, it's just assigning it via the '=' sign and in jQuery you don't have to use the '=' sign to assign a function to an event?

Comment: Understandable, the reason jQuery has become so popular is the fact it handles the DOM with ease, allowing for animation and manipulation in such a simple manor. [Here is a site with more information on learning basic JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript); take a look over the documentation for a better understanding.

Comment: In @faino's example, a function object (created by a function expression) is being assigned to the `onclick` property of a DOM element.  In JS functions are first class objects -- you can create anonymous functions with expressions, and assign them to variables or pass them to functions.  In @faino's example a function object is being assigned to a variable (property of an object).  In your question, a function object is being passed to a function.

Comment: Assigning a listener to a DOM object property like `onclick` is an old, outdated way of registering event listeners.  If anything you probably want to learn how to do it using the DOM (e.g. [addEventListener](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-registration)).  Be aware that Internet Explorer does not implement the standard DOM event interface -- that's one of the inconsistencies jQuery helps with.